# Why does my Nav show up differently in Dev Tools and on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I made a mobile navigation and the menu displays differently in chrome / edge dev tools than it does on actual mobile devices. (See Below). I have used every phone in dev tools mainly the iPhoneX. I have tested it on a iPhone XS max and iPhone 12 Pro max.

Dev Tools
[Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTGYP.png)
Mobile Devices
[Mobile Devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxAxJ.jpg)

```css
.nav {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: $darker-blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 125px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<!-- HEADER SECTION -->
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-content">
      <div class="header-img">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="img/cglogo.png" alt="Logo" height="50px" width="50px"> </a>
      </div>
                    
      <div class="nav" id="nav">
        <a href="index.html" class="nav-item active"> Home</a>
        <a href="portfolio.html" class="nav-item"> My Work</a>
        <a href="blog.html" class="nav-item"> Blog</a>
        <a href="contact.html" class="nav-item"> Contact</a>
      </div>

      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i style="color: #e7e7e7;" class="fa fa-bars fa-2x" id="bars"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Could you please add code? And which mobile device have you used?

Comment: specify the mobile phone device that you have used and also tell us which phone you have used in dev tools

Comment: @MetropolisCZ Updated with code. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes devtools will mess up, but its important that on a real phone the page looks normal, happened to me a lot of times i just check it out via my localhost and it looks fine, don't stress about it.

Answer (score 0):

Dev tools responsive size isn't as much as reliable as with the real mobile devices. I recommend having a mobile emulator and open your deployed website. Rely on devtool if you just want to see if your website is generally responsive but have it inspected in real/emulated mobile device. The view height of the devtool(which displays a full view) is significantly different as with what mobile devices display(also display navigation bar of the mobile and the notification and url bar of the mobile browser)
.